# Image Manipulation dynamic resize

Tags: php, image

I am using [this excellent image manipulation class](https://github.com/hungtrieu/html5-image-upload/blob/master/ImageManipulator.php) with my code below:

```php
if ($fileValidation->passed()) { 
//Upload the file 
$newNamePrefix = time() . '_'; 
//add a time prefic to the front of the file 
$manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']); //initialise the class 
$newImage = $manipulator->resample(300,300); // resizing to 300x300 
//Check there is space in their uploads dir after upload 
if (checkSpace($accountId, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] == true)) { 
//Save the file 
$manipulator->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.$accountId.'/'.$newNamePrefix
. $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']); // saving file to uploads folder 
//Insert a record into the uploads table 
$insertProfile = DB::getInstance()->insert('ym_uploads', array(
'account_id' => $accountId, 
'vessel_id' => $vid, 
'user_id' => $uid, 
'file_linked_table' => 'ym_expenditure',
'file_linked_id' => $item,
'file_name' => $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']
)); 
} else { Session::flashmessage('danger', 'We were unable to upload your receipt image as you have insuficient storage remaining'); } }
```

What I'm unsure how to approach is how to resize the image dynamically. E.g. the user uploads a picture from their phone. By setting the size to 300 x 300 I get a squashed image if the uploaded picture isn't square to start with.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to how to approach this? Essentially I am trying to reduce the file size taken up by the uploads.

I'm thinking find the image size to be uploaded, then set this as a percentage then add to the resample part of the code???

I'm currently working on...

```php
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($manipulator);
if ($width >= 4000) {
$width = $width / 8;
$height = $height / 8;
} elseif ($width >= 2000) {
$width = $width / 4;
$height = $height / 4;
} elseif ($width >= 500) {
$width = $width / 2;
$height = $height / 2;
}
$newImage = $manipulator->resample($width, $height); // resizing to 300x300
```

This throws

> Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Invalid resource

sadly so it's sending the wrong info to the class.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've got something working although it is probably not the best way to go about the process.

Using...

```html
$manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']); //initialise the class
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
if ($width >= 4000) {
$width = $width / 8;
$height = $height / 8;
} elseif ($width >= 2000) {
$width = $width / 4;
$height = $height / 4;
} elseif ($width >= 500) {
$width = $width / 2;
$height = $height / 2;
}
$newImage = $manipulator->resample($width, $height); // resizing to 300x300
```

Allows me to dynamically reduce the filesize based on the uploaded image and pass that resize into the class.